# Method not found error in Castle Windsor / NHibernate Integration Facility after version updates

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, castle-windsor

The following exception is observed after we upgraded  Castle Windsor from 2.5.2.0 to Castle Windsor 3.3 which is the latest version -

*Method not found: 'Void Castle.Core.DependencyModel..ctor(Castle.Core.DependencyType, System.String, System.Type, Boolean)*

**Stack Trace:**

```
*[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Castle.Core.DependencyModel..ctor(Castle.Core.DependencyType, System.String, System.Type, Boolean)'.]
   Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.Internal.NHSessionComponentInspector.ProcessModel(IKernel kernel, ComponentModel model) +0
   Castle.MicroKernel.ModelBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass6.<BuildModel>b__4(IContributeComponentModelConstruction c) +60
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action) +11702442
   Castle.MicroKernel.ModelBuilder.DefaultComponentModelBuilder.BuildModel(IComponentModelDescriptor[] customContributors) +223
   Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.ComponentRegistration`1.Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.IRegistration.Register(IKernelInternal kernel) +154
   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Register(IRegistration[] registrations) +179
   Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.NHibernateFacility.RegisterDefaultConfigurationBuilder() +398
   Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.NHibernateFacility.RegisterComponents() +221
   Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.NHibernateFacility.Init() +266
   Castle.MicroKernel.Facilities.AbstractFacility.Castle.MicroKernel.IFacility.Init(IKernel kernel, IConfiguration facilityConfig) +64
   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.AddFacility(String key, IFacility facility) +381
   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.AddFacility(IFacility facility) +124
   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.AddFacility(Action`1 onCreate) +165
   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.AddFacility(String key, Action`1 onCreate) +85
   Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.AddFacility(String idInConfiguration, Action`1 configureFacility) +113
   IoC.IoCBootstrapper.CreateBaseContainer(String configPath) 
   IoC.IoCBootstrapper.InitializeForWeb(String configPath) 
   Web.Global_asax.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)*
```

This is the sample code that configures NHibernate:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Kernel.ConfigurationStore.AddFacilityConfiguration("nHibernateFacility", Init());
container.AddFacility<NHibernateFacility>("nHibernateFacility", f => f.ConfigurationBuilder<FluentNHibernateConfigurationBuilder>());


public static MutableConfiguration Init(ProviderSchema schema, int factoryCount)
{
var facility = new MutableConfiguration("facility");
facility.Attributes.Add("id", "nhibernatefacility");
facility.Attributes.Add("isWeb", "true");
facility.Attributes.Add("type", "Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.NHibernateFacility, Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration");
CreateFactory(facility, factoryCount, schema);
 return facility;
}

public static void CreateFactory(MutableConfiguration facility, int id, ProviderSchema schema)
{
var factory = facility.CreateChild("factory");
factory.Attributes.Add("id", string.Format("nhibernate.factory{0}", id));
factory.Attributes.Add("alias", schema.Name);
 var settings = factory.CreateChild("settings");

settings.CreateItem("connection.driver_class", schema.ProviderFactory)
.CreateItem("connection.connection_string", schema.ProviderDatabase)
.CreateItem("proxyfactory.factory_class", "NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle")
.CreateItem("dialect", "NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect")
.CreateItem("cache.provider_class", "NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.SysCacheProvider, NHibernate.Caches.SysCache")
.CreateItem("cache.use_second_level_cache", "true")
.CreateItem("cache.default_expiration", "600")
.CreateItem("adonet.batch_size", "100")
.CreateItem("show_sql", "false");
}
```

The exception is thrown in container.AddFacility() call.

Below is the list of Castle Windsor and NHibernate assembly versions currently referenced in the projects:

- Castle.Core 3.3.0
- Castle.Windsor 3.3.0
- Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration 1.1.0.39
- Castle.Services.Transaction 2.5.0.0
- NHibernate 3.1.0.4000
- FluentNHibernate 2.0.0.0
- Iesi.Collections 2.1.0.4000

What version of Castle Windsor is compatible with NHibernate Integration Facility? Is there a patch available that I can download to resolve this issue?

I found a similar question on stackoverflow and an issue was logged on the projects tracker for a resolution. But this was Castle Windsor version 3.0 way back in Dec 2011, see the link below.

[Castle Windsor 3 + Fluent NHibernate + Castle.NHibernate.Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557327/castle-windsor-3-fluent-nhibernate-castle-nhibernate-integration)

Did the fix not make it in Castle.Core 3.3.0?

Or am I missing something here, any help / suggestion greatyl appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NHibernateIntegration facility 1.1.0 does not support Castle Windsor 3. The Castle Project hasn't been maintaining that facility for the last 4 years after the last maintainer moved on. [Issue FACILITIES-156](https://github.com/castleproject/castle-youtrack-export/blob/master/FACILITIES/FACILITIES-156.xml), logged in our old issue tracker died there after none of the users who made their own fork submitted a pull request, so no those patches were never applied.

See this issue on our issue tracker that was logged in September, with links to the source code that still lives in the Git repo and advice on bringing it back to life:
https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/issues/101